# Can I write duplicate node blocks in Puppet site.pp file?

Tags: puppet

I am trying to write duplicate node blocks in site.pp file. This site.pp file I am generating from Java code. When I do test 'puppetd --test' I am not getting other node blocks changes on client.

site.pp

```
    node "puppetclient1.domain.com" {
     file { "twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm" :
            source => "puppet:///files/modules/BIND/twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm",
     }
    }
    node "puppetclient1.domain.com" {
     package { "twc-bind" :
            source => "/opt/test/files/twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm",
            provider => "rpm",
            ensure => "latest",
     }
    }
   node "puppetclient1.domain.com" {
     service { "named" :
            subscribe => File["/opt/test/files/twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm"],
            ensure => "running",
     }
    }
```

Comment: why you want to do this way ?

Comment: Because I have 1000's of nodes and 100's of Files, Packages and Services. So, I thought If I do in this way it will reduce file size. I can give 
'node "domain1", "domain2", ... {
<FILE or PKG or SRVC info>
}'. If I do in this way I will get, no.of node blocks = no.of files + no.of pkgs + no.of srvc. Otherwise I have to write 1000 blocks for 1000 nodes with repeated files, pkgs and srvc information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that puppet will match against the first node it finds.

You need to make your Java code a little bit smarter and add *all* of the resources into a single node, i.e.

```
node "puppetclient1.domain.com" {

 file { "twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm" :
        source => "puppet:///files/modules/BIND/twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm",
 }

 package { "twc-bind" :
        source => "/opt/test/files/twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm",
        provider => "rpm",
        ensure => "latest",
 }

 service { "named" :
        subscribe => File["/opt/test/files/twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm"],
        ensure => "running",
 }
}
```

Or another option would be to use [node inheritance](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_node_definitions.html#inheritance).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah initially I wrote like that only it worked. if you find any other solution please reply again.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll have to deal with hundred of resources and thousands of boxes, you should care about make a good design and modeling. Put your resources into classes, and then classes into more general classes and then, put classes into boxes. And use hiera or parameterized classes or both to change resources

```
class twc-bind {
 file { "/opt/test/files/twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm" :
        source => "puppet:///files/modules/BIND/twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm",
 }
 package { "twc-bind" :
        source => "/opt/test/files/twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm",
        provider => "rpm",
        ensure => "latest",
 }
 service { "named" :
        ensure => "running",
 }
 File["twc-bind-9.9.4-0.noarch.rpm"]->Package["twc-bind"]->Service["named"]
}
node "puppetclient1.domain.com" {
 class { "twc-bind" :
 }
}
```

If you're using Java to generate manifests, you shuold model your Java classes too.